# how to add buttons programmatically in android

Tags: android, button, android-relativelayout

**I want something like this in my activity layout:**

[image]

If user click +Add Other then it should add a button programmatically. I have used relative layout but it's not working.

**Here is the code that I tried:**

```
View root;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pay_remind_fragment, container, false);

        Button b = new Button(getContext());
        Button b1 = new Button(getContext());
        Button b2 = new Button(getContext());
        Button b3 = new Button(getContext());
        Button b4 = new Button(getContext());


        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rl = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);;
        b.setLayoutParams(rl);

        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
        layout.addView(b);
        layout.addView(b1);
        layout.addView(b2);
        layout.addView(b3);
        layout.addView(b4);


        return root;
    }
```

Results are like this, which I don't want.

[image]

Comment: views are align on top left in relative layouts so you have build relationship between views for alignment

Comment: I did not get it, please help. Please give me the solution using code.

Comment: why are you making it from client side, make it from server side. on click add make a network call and update the list. To show all the list item use recycler view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case i want to suggest you to use `Flow` from `constraintLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`. You can learn more by reading this [article](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/constraintlayout-flow-simple-grid-building-without-nested-layouts/#:%7E:text=ConstraintLayout%20Flow%20allows%20a%20long,flexible%20box%20layout%20from%20CSS.).